# Chef: Upload and re-apply a cookbook to a Node

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

This is kind of a n00b question, but the Chef docs don't help.

Say I changed the code of a cookbook. I upload it to my chef server. Ho do I apply the changes to my nodes using this cookbook?

Comment: What about running chef-client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Draco commented, you run Chef on your node(s). They will automatically download the changed files in the cookbook from the server.

```
sudo chef-client
```

If you're running Chef as a service (setup via Opscode's [chef-client](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook service recipe or otherwise), it will automatically run at some point. Since you're using a Chef Server, you can also use `knife ssh` to perform a search and run the command on multiple nodes at one time.

```
knife ssh "*:*" "sudo chef-client" -x youruser
```

Replace "*:*" with any [Chef Search Query](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/essentials_search.html).

Also, this is where [Environments](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/essentials_environments.html) are useful, in that you can pin particular versions of cookbooks to nodes in an environment, so they don't get the changes that were made in the cookbook until you modify the version they're allowed to use. For example, if you have version 1.0.0 of your cookbook, and pin "production" to that ("= 1.0.0"), then increment the version (1.0.1) before uploading, then production nodes won't get the new version until the version in the environment is updated to the newer version.